# How could I annotate both property and params for a constructor value?

Tags: reflection, kotlin, annotations

I defined an annotation class for serialize/deserialize a model.

If I define **PROPERTY** as *Target* and

```
MyClass( @PropertyName("a_name") val name: String )
```

I can access *annotations* thought my class *property* but not thought my class *constructor params*.
Viceversa if I define no *Target* or both **PROPERTY** and **VALUE_PARAMETER**.

For access *annotation* for both *property* and *value params* I should annotate like this:

```
@param:PropertyName("a_name")
@property:PropertyName("a_name")
```

But I guess nobody would like this solution.

As a workaround I should just ***Target* the *value params*,** then **get both *constructor* ad *properties***, then **match by name every *constructor param* with *properties*** and **access *annotation* from *param* and *value* from *property*.**
It works, but I think I could find a better solution.

Any hints?